# ssh freeze while running vagrant up

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to setup an RHCE lab on my machine. I've installed vagrant version `Vagrant 2.1.4` and virtualbox 5 on ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded centos-7.0-x86_64.box from [https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-addinstall-and-run-centos-7-vagrant-box-to-virtualbox-using-vagrant/][1]

I installed vagrant plugins vagrant plugin  vagrant-vbguest &&  sahara

Here is my vagrant   script

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
server_disk='server.vdi'
desktop_disk='desktop.vdi'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.box = "centos/7"
 config.vm.define "classroom" do |s|
  s.vbguest.auto_update = false
  s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.254"
  s.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  #s.vm.synced_folder "../repos", "/repos", owner: "root", group: "root"
  s.vm.synced_folder "scripts/classroom", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  s.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/classroom.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/classroom.sh
  SHELL
 end

 config.vm.define "server" do |a|
  a.vbguest.auto_update = false
  a.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   unless File.exist?(server_disk)
    v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', server_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
   end
   v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', server_disk]
   end
  a.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
  a.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  a.vm.synced_folder "scripts/server", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  a.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/server.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/server.sh
  SHELL
  end

 config.vm.define "desktop" do |b|
  b.vbguest.auto_update = false
  b.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   unless File.exist?(desktop_disk)
    v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', desktop_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
   end
   v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', desktop_disk]
   end
  b.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  b.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  b.vm.synced_folder "scripts/desktop", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  b.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/desktop.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/desktop.sh
  SHELL
  end
end
```

When I run **sudo vagrant up**

I get error

```
An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses.
The error message is shown below. In many cases, errors from this
library are caused by ssh-agent issues. Try disabling your SSH
agent or removing some keys and try again.

If the problem persists, please report a bug to the net-ssh project.

timeout during server version negotiating
```

I am following this https://github.com/frezbo/lab .Please do help me.